# Ubuntu doesn't show up on the boot menu

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I just installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 from a flash drive.
It said it installed properly and that I needed to restart. But when I did I never got the option to boot to Ubuntu and even when I pull up the boot list on start up it only shows Windows 7 with no option for Ubuntu.

edit: Added what I installed it from.

Comment: Does it directly boot into windows or atleast the grub shows up?

Comment: It directly boots into windows.

Comment: what happen when you hold shift key at booting  ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install grub again. This can be done using a live Ubuntu on a USB disk. After loging  into live Ubuntu run this:

```
 sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/media/pathToYourUbuntuParition sda
```

Answer (score 0):

Start ubuntu live from CD. Run:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This will list all the drives in your system. Mount the partition that contains ubuntu installation,

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

sda1 is just an example. Use your ubuntu partition. Then install grub

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/ /dev/sda
```

and, update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

This will work! Try it..

Comment: running this command returns that the install device wasnt specified.

Comment: which of these command?

Comment: sudo grub-install --root-directory=//dev/sda

Comment: In the second command, you need to specify the partition sda1 or sda2 or whatever it is. In the third command, you need to give sda itself. No changes

Comment: and there is a space between the two /

Comment: i did the sda6 in the second command, when i put the space i get boot/grub is not readable by grub on boot

Comment: You are trying to install as a root user, right? Could you please share one screenshot or something?

Answer (score 0):

There is also a bug in the installer that does not delay when the install reports as done and when grub is also written. It does not flush file writes immediately, so if you restart **AS SOON** as the install says it is done, it kills all processes and *sometimes* grub has not been written yet.

next time, when the install says it is done, *wait half a minute*. **Then** click restart and that doesn't happen. This elusive bug got me, and I meant to report it but never have.